# Get changes from the perforce

Tags: perforce

I am trying to get last changes from the perforce

So I go to perforce folder and executing following command, as I found in tuturial

```
p4 changes -m 5 //depot/main//project/ result.txt // should save last five changes to result.txt
```

but gives me the following error

```
result.txt - must create client 'IM000001' to access local files // IM000001 is the name of my computer
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try writing the command like this:

```
p4 changes -m 5 //depot/main/project/... > result.txt
```

The main thing you got wrong was no redirection of the output into your result.txt file so p4 changes tried to interpret result.txt as a versioned file, but without a valid client spec (aka workspace) it couldn't resolve the depot path for it.